# How do I stop a python program once a variable reaches 0 or less?

Tags: function, loops, while-loop

I am building a text rpg for my CS class project. Everything works, except my lose condition. It seems like such a simple issue, and I must be overlooking a simple answer.

```
while health > 0:
     opening()
     if health <= 0:
          lose_condition()
```

If the health variable reaches 0 or less, the program keeps running as usual. The if statement for health <= 0 never calls.

Comment: I assume opening() changes the value of health? Is health changing a local copy of health and not the global health? Add a print(health) after the call to opening() and see what happens

Comment: @Chris The health variable is set globally at 100, and upon executing opening() it stays at 100 until brought down by a separate combat function. Each function that pertains to health has it globally called.

Answer (score 0):

We do not have the full code, so here is a quick demo working with a comment showing how to break it. My assumption is that the combat functions are not correctly scoping the variables as global, or alternately, something else is continually resetting health.

```
import threading
import time

def attack_thread():
    global health # If you comment out, it is not global, you never decrease the global
    print('Damage thread start ' + str(health))
    while health >= 0:
        health -= 9
        time.sleep(0.5)
    print('Damage thread end ' + str(health))

def game_loop():
    global health
    health = 100
    attack = threading.Thread(target=attack_thread)
    attack.start()
    while health > 0:
        print('current health ' + str(health))
        if health <= 0:
            print('player died')

game_loop()
```